# Need an elegant solution to declare the value of two variables based on the count of the post

Tags: code

I'm displaying three posts (custom post types) with a foreach loop, each displaying an audio player and some metadata. The audio is played via JW Player, which I am calling using their api. There is a function in the JW Player code that allows you to stop any other players from playing if you press one player.

Here's the whole loop. It does the job but I would like something more elegant and dynamic:

```
<?php 
    $posts = get_posts(array(
        'numberposts' => 3,
        'post_type' => 'audio'
    ));
    if( $posts ): 
    $i = 1; 
?>
<?php foreach( $posts as $post ) : ?>
    <div class="media-container audio player-<?php echo $i; ?>">
        <div id="player-<?php echo $i; ?>">Loading this Audio...</div>
<?php 
if ($i == 1) :
    $x1 = 2;
    $x2 = 3;
elseif ($i == 2) :
    $x1 = 1;
    $x2 = 3;
elseif ($i == 3) :
    $x1 = 1;
    $x2 = 2;
endif;
?>
        <script type="text/javaScript">
            var playerInstance = jwplayer("player-<?php echo $i; ?>");
            playerInstance.setup({
                file: '<?php the_field("audio_upload"); ?>',
                image: '<?php the_field("audio_image"); ?>',
                events:{
                    onPlay: function() {
                        jwplayer('player-<?php echo $x1; ?>').stop();
                        jwplayer('player-<?php echo $x2; ?>').stop();
                    }
                }
            });
        </script>

        <div class="media-details">
            <h2 class="audio-title"><?php the_field('name_of_audio'); ?>    </h2>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php $i++; endforeach; wp_reset_postdata(); endif; ?>
```

I'm wondering if there isn't a way to dynamically get $x1 and $x2 rather than explicitly declaring the values like I am doing. For example if I decide to have 4 or 5 (or 10) posts show up on this page I would like to not have to change the code for $x1 and $x2. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: hmmm this question has very little to do with wordpress :(

Comment: Sorry @MarkKaplun I always work with Wordpress and I always post here. Where do you suggest I post?

Comment: first, no need to appologies ;) stackoverflow is probably a better place. as your question is basically how to generate some semi random numbers. You can just use random number generator for that. (or maybe I misunderstood the question)

Comment: @MarkKaplun it's not a random number generator, and it is about about working within a Wordpress query, but yes it also could be a question for just stackoverflow. Noted for next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a second `for` loop that will output the `stop function` for all the players except the current one, like this:

```
<?php

$posts = get_posts(array(
    'numberposts' => 3,
    'post_type' => 'any'
));

$number_of_posts_returned = count($posts); //because it can be less than the ones we wanted

if ($posts):
    $i = 1;
    ?>
    <?php foreach ($posts as $post) : ?>
        <div class="media-container audio player-<?php echo $i; ?>">
            <div id="player-<?php echo $i; ?>">Loading this Audio...</div>
            <script type="text/javaScript">
                var playerInstance = jwplayer("player-<?php echo $i; ?>");
                playerInstance.setup({
                file: '<?php //the_field("audio_upload"); ?>',
                image: '<?php //the_field("audio_image"); ?>',
                events:{
                    onPlay: function() {
                        <?php 
                        //lets create the stop call for all except the current number
                        for ($x = 1; $x <= $number_of_posts_returned; $x++) { 
                            if($x != $i){
                       ?>
                            jwplayer('player-<?php echo $x; ?>').stop();

                      <?php }//end IF

                        } //end for
                       ?>

                    }
                }
                });
            </script>

            <div class="media-details">
                <h2 class="audio-title"><?php //the_field('name_of_audio'); ?>    </h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php $i++;
    endforeach;
    wp_reset_postdata();
endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks this worked! And it looks future proof. I learned something new, I did not know you could put PHP inside of Javascript, although I can't see why not now :) Makes total sense. @moraleida thank you too... I tried your version and adding a new class to the player div unfortunately broke the player. JW dynamically loads a bunch of classes of its own. I even tried your way using one of their classes ('jwplayer') that loads for each instance, but it was still broken, not sure why. But I did incorporate your esc_js() into David's code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution just based on getting the IDs from the current loaded players.

First, add a common class to you player divs:

`<div id="player-<?php echo $i; ?>" class="jwplayer-loaded">Loading this Audio...</div>`

Then on your script, get all current loaded players and stop them one by one except your current one:

```
<script type="text/javaScript">
    // don't forget to esc_js() any values you print to javascript code
    // https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_js/
    var playerId = "player-<?php echo esc_js( $i ); ?>",
        playerInstance = jwplayer( playerId );
    playerInstance.setup({
        file: '<?php the_field("audio_upload"); ?>',
        image: '<?php the_field("audio_image"); ?>',
        events:{
            onPlay: function() {
                var playerList = document.querySelectorAll('.jwplayer-loaded');

                [].forEach.call( playerList, function( v ) {
                    if ( v.id !== playerId ) {
                        jwplayer( v.id ).stop();
                    }
                } );
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```